two-dimensional ellipsoid line element
What is the line element/metric of a two-dimensional tri-axial ellipsoid? Can it be diagonalized? I have been trying to find it for hours and for some reason it isn't used much in literature.
I am trying to find a simple version in the right coordinates so that it would have relatively easier vielbein choices which will help me calculate the curvature using the Cartan equations.

We may use principal patches

Due to Jacobi:

\begin{align}
  X &= a\,
  \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2\sin^2 \beta-c^2\cos^2 \beta}}{\sqrt{a^2-c^2}}
  \, \cos \omega \\
  Y &= b\cos \beta \sin \omega \\
  Z &= c\sin \beta \,
  \frac{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 \omega+b^2\cos^2 \omega-c^2}}{\sqrt{a^2-c^2}} \\
  ds^2 &= (a^2\sin^2 \omega+
           b^2(\cos^2 \omega-\sin^2 \beta)-
           c^2\cos^2 \beta) \\
  & \qquad \times
  \left(
    \frac{b^2\sin^2 \beta+c^2\cos^2 \beta}
    {a^2-b^2\sin^2 \beta-c^2\cos^2 \beta} d\beta+
    \frac{a^2\sin^2 \omega+b^2\cos^2 \omega}
    {a^2\sin^2 \omega+b^2\cos^2 \omega-c^2} d\omega
  \right)
\end{align}

In confocal ellipsoidal coordinates, for any confocal ellipsoids, hyperboloid of one/two sheets, by setting either one of $d\lambda$, $d\mu$ or $d\nu$ to be zero accordingly:

$$ds^2=
h_\lambda^2 \,d\lambda^2+
h_\mu^2 \,d\mu^2+
h_\nu^2 \,d\nu^2$$

Thank you very much! Concerning the Jacobi line element, do you have the source or calculation? I have been trying to verify it but cannot see how terms like $sin^2(\omega ^ 2) $ appear.

@jad typo corrected
